looking for a memory efficient data structure for slightly different HTTP flows
I'm trying to create an HTTP fuzzing API in python in which I wish to store HTTP requests and responses for later analysis like searching whole content and viewing requests and responses, now as I'm fuzzing an endpoint most of the requests and responses only differ by a couple of words, some html tags, or json content.
for example fuzzing an URL with non-existing paths would generate the same 404 response message ( or might indicate that path X doesn't exist on the server ) but still most of the response body is the same across all the responses.
this would make the API memory inefficient if used with big wordlists.
now what I'm asking is that, is there a python package, or a specific data structure that I can use for a generic content type (even if it doesn't work with binary data ) that can be used to make the API more memory efficient ?
and if not, how hard is it to make such a data structure if it is even plausible ?

I don't think there's a pre-fact data structure that could do this very efficiently, but you could come up with a thing that looks at past recorded responses to look for repeated chunks and deduplicate them (which is basically just generic data compression, of course).

isn't using a data compression algorithm would be very slow if I'm to investigate individual flows, for example if I have 20k requests compressed and I want to investigate a single flow, it would take considerable amount of time to decompress the data to deal with that flow ?

Depends on the algorithm. TBH I would start without thinking about compression/optimization/whatever and only consider it if it becomes an actual issue...

actually it is an issue for me right now :), I have been testing it and it sometimes takes 3G of RAM when running with big wordlists.

What are these wordlists you talk about? Why do you need to keep everything in memory?
